# Are readers favored over writers in read writer spin lock

Tags: c, concurrency, linux-kernel, synchronization, linux-device-driver

> A final important consideration in using the Linux reader-writer spin
>   locks is that they favor readers over writers. If the read lock is
>   held and a writer is waiting for exclusive access, readers that
>   attempt to acquire the lock continue to succeed.

Is this still correct.

Because i am not seeing the behavior.

When i acquired a read lock , and it is still in the critical section, i tried to acquire write lock and then read lock and i found write lock is acquired and the second read lock is acquired only after write lock is released.

Is the above still valid?

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/rwlock_types.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/kthread.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

DEFINE_RWLOCK(mylock);
static struct task_struct *thread1, *thread2, *thread3;

int counter = 0;

static int write_threadfn(void *arg)
{
    pr_info("processor:%d trying to acquire write lock\n", smp_processor_id());
    write_lock(&mylock);
    pr_info("processor:%d acquired write lock\n", smp_processor_id());
    counter++;
    msleep(7000);
    write_unlock(&mylock);
    pr_info("processor%d released write lock\n", smp_processor_id());
    return 0;
}

static int read_threadfn(void *arg)
{
    pr_info("processor:%d trying to acquire read lock\n", smp_processor_id());
    read_lock(&mylock);
    pr_info("processor:%d acquired read lock\n", smp_processor_id());
    pr_info("processor%d\t counter:%d\n", smp_processor_id(), counter);
    msleep(5000);
    read_unlock(&mylock);
    pr_info("processor:%d releasing read lock\n", smp_processor_id());
    return 0;
}

static int __init test_hello_init(void)
{
    thread1 = kthread_run(read_threadfn, NULL, "thread1");
    thread3 = kthread_run(write_threadfn, NULL, "thread2");
    thread2 = kthread_run(read_threadfn, NULL, "thread2");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit test_hello_exit(void)
{
}

module_init(test_hello_init);
module_exit(test_hello_exit);
```

dmesg:

```
[ 2099.161159] processor:5 trying to acquire read lock
[ 2099.161160] processor:5 acquired read lock
[ 2099.161160] processor5    counter:0
[ 2099.161309] processor:0 trying to acquire write lock
[ 2099.161452] processor:1 trying to acquire read lock
[ 2104.220136] processor:5 releasing read lock
[ 2104.220137] processor:0 acquired write lock
[ 2111.388005] processor0 released write lock
[ 2111.388006] processor:1 acquired read lock
[ 2111.388006] processor1    counter:1
[ 2116.509004] processor:1 releasing read lock
```

Comment: You cannot acquire the write lock while the read lock is held. I suggest you show your test code.

Comment: What context does this documentation come from? Is it from your Linux distro's documentation? Or some random internet persona?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I assume when OP says acquire they mean attempt to acquire, since in their code it's basically the same?

Comment: This statement seems obvious. If you have `n` writers and `n` readers but you can only ever have a single writer -or- any number of readers on the resource, it's pretty clear that any given reader will have a much higher chance of acquiring the resource because it only has to compete with the writers, whereas writers have to compete with _every other writer_ in addition to readers. When the lock is available, almost every writer attempt to get the lock will fail--the last reader needs to give up the lock and all other readers need to fail to acquire. Please show your code as a [mcve]. Thanks!

Comment: Attached code and dmesg output.

Comment: @corsiKa, the documentation is from Linux Kernel Development by Robert Love

Comment: I'm not sure it's ever been the case (until the introduction of the qrwlock code in 3.16) that readers ever jumped the queue ahead of writers when contending for the same rwlock. As far as I can tell, they had equal priority. However, architectures using the qrwlock code (since 3.16) do allow readers in an interrupt context to jump the queue ahead of writers (see `queued_read_lock_slowpath()` in "kernel/locking/qrwlock.c").